# Why Do I need to renderToString twice for react server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

My current server-side node server uses very similar setup to redux-saga real-word example.

It uses renderToString twice, which seems different from another example.

**real-world server.js**

```
 const rootComp = <Root store={store} routes={routes} history={createMemoryHistory()} renderProps={renderProps} type="server"/>


  store.runSaga(rootSaga).toPromise().then(() => {
    console.log('sagas complete')
    res.status(200).send(
      layout(
        renderToString(rootComp),
        JSON.stringify(store.getState())
      )
    )
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.message)
    res.status(500).send(e.message)
  })

  renderToString(rootComp)
  store.close()
```

Another example just uses renderToString once. Can you guys explain why it needs to do renderToString twice with redux-saga ??

Answer (score 0):

The first call (the one at the bottom) will render your App. It will dispatch every of your components actions and then use Saga to fetch / store datas.

Then you're calling store.close() that will stopping Saga to do more things (if you not stopping Saga, it's gonna wait forever because of the while(true) of Saga).

The second call (inside the promise) will render your app with the data that is stored inside your store. No more actions will be treated by Saga as you stopped it.

There is examples with only one "renderToString" because. Choose one :

- there is no data to load, so no need to render twice
- data are loaded by another way